# Incorrect value for field 'Signature': value is 662655099 but 67324752 expected

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-gradle-plugin

I've been working with Firebase Database.The code was working fine for Firebase Authentication but showed this error message when added Firebase Database.

Incorrect value for field 'Signature': value is 662655099 but 67324752 expected.

Following is the gradle script:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'


android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sudhanshujaisani.mywhatsapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner             
"android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 
'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you also added `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'`? Does it work when you add this dependency?

Comment: Yes I've added it. Still doesn't works

Comment: Do you have the same error or another one?

Comment: yes still the same error @AlexMamo

Answer (score 2):

I don't really know what causes this error but I had it too and I figured out (after some research) that it's something going on with Instant Run. It hasn't got anything to do with firebase, but I think it's something about Gradle and importing packages.

Anyway, I figured disabling Instant Run as a simple workaround and it worked! :)

**In Android Studio:**

1. File -> Settings (or press Ctrl+Alt+S).
2. Build, Execution, Deployment -> Instant Run (on the left panel).
3. Uncheck the first checkbox "Enable Instant Run to hot swap code/resource changes on deploy (default enabled)".

If you actually need Instant Run, this workaround won't help. I'm still trying to find the actual solution.

Answer (score 2):

Invalidate Cache & Restart didn't work for me.

Try,

1. Build -> Clean Project
2. Build -> Rebuild project

Answer (score 0):

File -> Invalidate Caches/Restart -

Answer (score 0):

Update your android sdk, partial installations cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's something about Gradle and importing packages.

Anyway, I figured disabling Instant Run as a simple workaround and it worked! :)

In Android Studio:

File -> Project Structure(or press Ctrl+Alt+Shift+S).
Project-> Update the Latest Gradle Plugin Version
then Apply and ok, or Update the Project Gradle Plugin Version
they work for me.